# Finding or designing a thermochromic that becomes transparent to NIR at room temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, optical-properties, nanotechnology

Are there known nanoparticles or organic materials that have the following properties:

- absorb near-infrared light and convert them to heat at temperatures below a certain threshold
- become mostly transparent to NIR at temperatures above the threshold.

The threshold should be somewhere between -10 and 30° C.

If such compounds do not exist, how would you design them? I'm thinking of somehow coupling a gold nanorod with a PCM that "breaks" the rod when changing phase, but unclear how that could actually be designed.